# C# 4.0 PInvoke Issue (ATI AGS Library)

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, pinvoke

I downloaded the ATI AGS (ATI GPU Services) Libary, and am attempting to retrieve some basic driver information using this API, from C#. The ATI AGS library is available for download from here:

http://developer.amd.com/gpu/ags/Pages/default.aspx

I wrote a little bit of C# code to pull driver information from the GPU using the AGS API, but I'm having some trouble calling the unmanaged method. I've tried all sorts of different permutations of DllImportAttribute parameters, to no avail. I'm getting either a MarshalDirectiveException or a pInvokeStackImbalance.

I'm pretty sure that this is all due to an incorrect P/Invoke signature, but I have exhausted my knowledge of this API.

By the way, as an aside, you'll see that I'm using the 32-bit DLL, and I seem to be getting farther with it, but when I use the 64-bit DLL, I get a BadImageFormatException.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
    [DllImport(
            "atiags.dll"
            , PreserveSig=false
            , ExactSpelling=true
            , ThrowOnUnmappableChar=true
            , CharSet=CharSet.Unicode
            , EntryPoint="agsDriverGetVersionInfo"
    )]
    public static extern void agsDriverGetVersionInfo(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)]
        out agsDriverVersionInfoStruct DriverInfo
    );

    public static agsDriverVersionInfoStruct GetAgsDriverVersion()
    {
       agsDriverVersionInfoStruct DriverInfo = new agsDriverVersionInfoStruct();
       agsDriverGetVersionInfo(out DriverInfo);
    }

    public struct agsDriverVersionInfoStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
        public string strDriverVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string strCatalystVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public string strCatalystWebLink;
    }
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Here is the definition of the ATIAGSDriverGetVersionInfo() function in ati_ags.h. According to the ATI AGS documentation (a PDF included in the download), it says to define _ATI_AGS_USE_DLL, so I added this line at the top of my C# class code file:

**Documentation Quote**

Determine if AGS functionality will be accessed through a dll or static lib. If the dll option is chosen, make sure to define _ATI_AGS_USE_DLL in your project properties. If the static lib option is chosen, no special token needs to be defined.

```
__inline AGSReturnCode ATIAGSDriverGetVersionInfo( AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct *lpDriverVersionInfo )
{
AGSReturnCode iReturnValue = AGS_SUCCESS;

// Validate params
if ( NULL == lpDriverVersionInfo )
{
    return AGS_FAILURE;
}

#ifdef _ATI_AGS_USE_DLL
// Load the lib
HINSTANCE lib = NULL;
lib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("atiags.dll"));
if (NULL == lib)
{
    lib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("atiags64.dll"));
    if (NULL == lib)
    {
        return AGS_FAILURE;     
    }
}

// Get the function pointer
AGSDRIVERGETVERSIONINFO agsDriverGetVersionInfo = NULL;
agsDriverGetVersionInfo = (AGSDRIVERGETVERSIONINFO)GetProcAddress(lib, "agsDriverGetVersionInfo");
if (NULL == agsDriverGetVersionInfo)
{
    FreeLibrary(lib);
    return AGS_FAILURE;
}
#endif // _ATI_AGS_USE_DLL

// Get the number of GPUs
iReturnValue = agsDriverGetVersionInfo( lpDriverVersionInfo );

#ifdef _ATI_AGS_USE_DLL
// Free the lib
FreeLibrary(lib);
#endif // _ATI_AGS_USE_DLL

return iReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: So this works on .NET 3.5 and below?

Comment: I tried targeting the .NET 2.0 framework and got a ExecutionEngineException. All the problems happen when I invoke agsDriverGetVersionInfo().

Comment: You are going to have to use the same approach as the C sample code. P/Invoke declarations wont work here.

Comment: `pInvokeStackImbalance` suggests that you're calling the method with the wrong calling convention: which values of the `CallingConvention` property of the `DllImportAttribute` have you tried? BTW, I see no reason why p/invoke can't be made to work.

Comment: Can you expand on that at all? For what reason can't I use P/Invoke?

Comment: @RichardCook: Yes, I pointed that out in my post.

Comment: How is the function pointer `AGSDRIVERGETVERSIONINFO` defined? Is there a `typedef` declaration for this somewhere in the header file?

Comment: @RichardCook: Yes, there is a definition for AGSDRIVERGETVERSIONINFO in the header file.

Comment: @RichardCook: I just changed the CallingConvention to CallingConvention.ThisCall, and I am no longer getting the exception when calling the method. I am getting null values for the properties that should be set on the agsDriverVersionInfoStruct object (eg. strCatalystVersion).

Comment: This is the entire header file: http://pastebin.com/5fkB1anN

Comment: Where would I specify StringBuilder?

Comment: The documentation states the definition for strDriverVersion is: strDriverVersion[256], and strCatalystVersion is: strCatalystVersion[256]

Comment: @Trevor Sullivan: You will have to use `LoadLibrary` and delegates for function pointers. Like the C sample code.

Comment: @leppie: Can you explain why that is? What indication is there that I can't use P/Invoke?

Comment: @Trevor Sullivan: That is the way such libraries works. None of the methods are explicitly exported from the DLL. You can confirm this by using dumpbin.

Comment: Hmmmm, I opened the DLL with Dependency Walker, and it showed 4 exported functions (I believe). Now, I'm not very good with low-level programming, but was I misinterpreting something? What would it look like if the functions were exported?

Comment: @Trevor Sullivan: If that is the case, you CAN use P/Invoke, but it is still not going to work on both 32 and 64 bit, you will need to have different p/invoke methods for that, seeing the 64 bit dll's name is different.

Comment: @leppie: I couldn't get very far with the 64-bit DLL, so that's why I was using the 32-bit one. The 64-bit DLL threw a BadImageFormatException, I think because I'm using Visual C# 2010 Express, and it's targeting a 32-bit platform by default (can't change in the GUI). I'd have to hack the config file to change the target platform to 64-bit, I believe.

There's no reason I can't continue to test with the 32-bit DLL though, is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick for me...

```
public enum AGSReturnCode
{
    AGS_ERROR_MISSING_DLL = -2,
    AGS_ERROR_LEGACY_DRIVER = -1,
    AGS_FAILURE = 0,
    AGS_SUCCESS = 1
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string strDriverVersion;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string strCatalystVersion;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
    public string strCatalystWebLink;
}

public static class AGSharp
{
    [DllImport("atiags.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "agsDriverGetVersionInfo")]
    public static extern AGSReturnCode agsDriverGetVersionInfo(out AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct driver_info);
}
```

... seems like the wrong calling convention was causing troubles (like Richard pointed out already)

Answer (score 0):

In `ati_ags.h` the `AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct` struct is declared as follows:

```
typedef struct _AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct {
  char strDriverVersion[256];
  char strCatalystVersion[256];
  char strCatalystWebLink[256];
} AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct;
```

Here's how I would declare the equivalent in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct AGSDriverVersionInfoStruct {
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
  public string strDriverVersion;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
  public string strCatalystVersion;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
  public string strCatalystWebLink;
}
```

Comment: Cannot marshal field 'strDriverVersion' of type 'ATI_Config_Reader.agsDriverVersionInfoStruct': Struct or class fields cannot be of type StringBuilder. The same effect can usually be achieved by using a String field and preinitializing it to a string with length matching the length of the appropriate buffer.

Comment: Try with `SizeConst` and using `string` instead.

Comment: Trying to change back to System.String and initialize them to 256 characters in the constructor ....

Comment: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct agsDriverVersionInfoStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst=256)]
        public string strDriverVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string strCatalystVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 256)]
        public string strCatalystWebLink;

        public agsDriverVersionInfoStruct(int dummy)
        {
            strDriverVersion = "";
            strCatalystVersion = "";
            strCatalystWebLink = "";
        }
    }

Comment: It's still returning null values for these fields.

Comment: Have you set `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi`? You should also set that in the p/invoke declaration for `agsDriverGetVersionInfo`.

Comment: I did also try that. I forced it to both Ansi and Unicode. Both continue to return null values.

One interesting thing that's missing in the doc is the 3rd property, strCatalystWebLink. It's in the typedef in the header, but not the documentation. They're all defined as 256 bytes ... so I also tried forcing the struct size to 768 bytes, but that didn't help at all either.

Comment: If you set `PreserveSig` to `true` and declare the return type as `int`, what value does the method return?

Comment: Null also. Same for void retval.

Comment: If by "null" you mean zero, this corresponds to `AGS_FAILURE` so there must be something else wrong with the method p/invoke declaration. Hopefully somebody with more ATI knowledge than me can help you out!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's null, because I am echoing the results to a MessageBox, and it's empty. I also tried getting a retval of _AGSReturnCode by declaring that enum in my C# code and marshaling those values also -- I failed also at that. I appreciate your insight!

Comment: I've submitted a ticket to AMD's developer center. The ticket ID# is 1125, for anyone wanting to reference it. Cheers